# Output from shell_exec is no longer returned to PHP when including pyCuda

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, cuda, pycuda

I am calling this python file:

```
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print sys.argv[1]
```

From PHP like this:

```
$param = "hello";
$result = shell_exec("python /path/to/python/file.py " . $param);
echo $result;
```

Which works great as hello is displayed when running the PHP file. However, when I import pyCuda (2012.1) into the python file, the output is no longer returned to PHP even though it is still shown when running the command from bash. This is the python file with pyCuda imported:

```
from pycuda import driver as drv
from pycuda import tools
from pycuda import autoinit
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print sys.argv[1]
```

Why does PHP no longer receive the output when pyCuda is imported and what is the best way to read the output from this python file in PHP?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you running this from within a webserver? Maybe the imports cause some error, and the error message is going to stderr (and therefore to the server log) instead of stdout. Look into your server log, or try appending `2>&1` to your command.

Comment: Yes I am running this on a webserver. I have checked the logs but there are no reported errors. The python file seems to be working fine as it returns a response when run directly in a shell, just not from PHP via shell_exec.

Comment: The webserver process is usually running as different user, which normally has very limited permissions, so it's not the same as running it from the shell. I have not much experience with cuda, but I could imagine that a user wanting to use it at least needs to be in the 'video' group to access the `/dev/nvidia*` stuff.

Comment: Your were right mata, it was to do with the fact that the webserver user didn't have enough access. I ran **sudo su www-data** before the python file in the shell and saw the errors which I fixed using sudoers. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I hope you created a user with the rigth access rights/groups and don't run them as root, as that might be a big security risk.

Answer (score 1):

`pycuda.autoinit` registers an `atexit` autohandler to clean up the CUDA context it creates so that the python code exits gracefully. It is likely that this is terminating the application without flushing stdout, so the output never gets emitted.

So either try explicit flushing of stdout:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
sys.stdout.flush()
```

or don't use `pycuda.autoinit` and handle setup and pull down of the driver API context yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but adding **sys.stdout.flush()** doesn't make any different. I have reduced the imports to just **from pycuda import driver as drv** which still stops the output getting to PHP.